# Getting size of string with multiple '/000' characters

Tags: c, string

I have a string containing binary data.
Size of the string is 4. Other functions write data to it.
Every time, data is of different size as follows,

```
buf[0] = '\037';
buf[1] = buf[2]=buf[3] ='\000';
```

or

```
buf[0] = '\037';
buf[1] =  '\045';
buf[2]=buf[3] ='\000';
```

When I get the length of the string, I get 1 and 2 respectively in above cases.
I want the length of string to be 4 in all cases.

How should I deal with the terminating character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every C string function assumes that the NULL byte '\0' designates the end of a string. You cannot have a string with a NULL byte as content and use the standard C-string functions.

You will need to build your own string system. Note you will need some other way to figure out where your string ends.

Answer (score -2):

Try using double quotes to initialize strings

```
buf[0] = "\037";
buf[1] = buf[2]=buf[3] ="\000";
```

What u have initialized is a character with single quotes

Comment: '\0' and "\0" -- both are same

Comment: Yes '\0' and "\0" are both same but "\037" and '\037' are not the same